# Map an app to all folders/files in a directory recursively

Tags: powershell

I'm hoping to use Powershell to:

- Recurse through directories, of various depths, with the current PS
  script's directory being root
- Apply an app to those directories (which in turn will process the files within it)
- Which also requires an input of a new subdir to make base

The command I want to apply to each directory takes the format:
c:\xrv\fileprocess.exe -folderIn [dir] -foldorOut [newdir]

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to make this happen. I've tried to hash together something from snippets online but I never seem to have success. I've kind of made a part hodgepodge snippet part pseudo code attempt to explain what I'm trying to do below.

I'd also note that the paths are looong!

Thanks all!

```
Clear-Host
$StartDirectory = '\.'
echo $StartDirectory
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $StartDirectory -Recurse -Directory `|
foreach($dir in $dirs){
c:\xrv\fileprocess.exe -folderIn $dir -foldorOut "$dir\pd"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to not change too much from your code. try this:
if the $dir\pd dosent exist, does the program create it? if not then you would have to include a `mkdir $dir\pd` inside the foreach loop.

```
Clear-Host
$StartDirectory = '\.'
$exe = 'c:\xrv\fileprocess.exe'
Write-Host $StartDirectory
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $StartDirectory -Recurse -Directory
foreach ($dir in $dirs)
{
   &$exe -folderIn $dir -foldorOut "$dir\pd"
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kiran!
I had to add  ".FullName" after $dir as the directory seemed to fragment is some way. I also changed -$dir\pd to add it to a pd subdir of the root as the script currently made a new folder in every single folder and then re-looped through those too, never ending! Never really worked out why.

Comment: welcome Alan :) .... ah yes...`$dir` is an object so I should have included the property .fullname instead of the entire directory object...anyway good job in figuring that out.... the `$dir` is a variable that represents the current item(directory) being iterated against...the `$dirs` variable shouldnt have updated itself so I am not sure why it looped through the new dirs that were created.

Comment: Thanks again! Yes I'm still not sure what's going on with the logic there!